# Using Crosstab to Generate Data for Charts

Tags: postgresql-9.6

I'm trying to make an efficient query to create a view that will contains counts for the number of successful logins by day as well as by type of user with no duplicate users per day.

I have 3 tables involved in this query.  One table that contains all successful login attempts, one table for standard user accounts, and one table for admin user accounts.  All user_id values are unique across the entire database so there are no user accounts that will share the same user_id with an admin account:

```
TABLE 1: user_account
 user_id | username 
---------|----------
 1       | user1
 2       | user2

TABLE 2: admin_account
 user_id | username 
---------|----------
 6       | admin6
 7       | admin7

TABLE 3: successful_logins
 user_id | timestamp 
---------|------------------------------
 1       | 2022-01-23 14:39:12.63798-07
 1       | 2022-01-28 11:16:45.63798-07
 1       | 2022-01-28 01:53:51.63798-07
 2       | 2022-01-28 15:19:21.63798-07
 6       | 2022-01-28 09:42:36.63798-07
 2       | 2022-01-23 03:46:21.63798-07
 7       | 2022-01-28 19:52:16.63798-07
 2       | 2022-01-29 23:12:41.63798-07
 2       | 2022-01-29 18:50:10.63798-07
```

The resulting view I would like to generate would contain the following information from the above 3 tables:

```
VEIW: login_counts
 date_of_login | successful_user_logins | successful_admin_logins
---------------|------------------------|-------------------------
 2022-01-23    | 1                      | 1
 2022-01-28    | 2                      | 2
 2022-01-29    | 1                      | 0
```

I'm currently reading up on how crosstabs work but having trouble figuring out how to write the query based on my table setups.

I actually was able to get the values I needed by using the following query:

```
SELECT 
    to_char(s.timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS login_date,
    count(distinct u.user_id) AS successful_user_logins,
    count(distinct a.user_id) AS successful_admin_logins
FROM successful_logins s
LEFT JOIN user_account u ON u.user_id= s.user_id
LEFT JOIN admin_account a ON a.user_id= s.user_id
GROUP BY login_date
```

However, I was told it would be even quicker using crosstabs, especially considering the successful_logins table contains millions of records.  So I'm trying to also create a version of the query using crosstabs then comparing both execution times.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it isn't possible to do what I was asking about using crosstabs, so the original query I have will have to do.